# What's the difference between total, current and relative strength?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

When you hover over a person in their dynastic tree, you will be able to get an idea of how many troops they can summon. There are several numbers, but I can't figure out which I should look at.

[image: Screen-cap showing relative strength figures]

Now, what I *think*, is that the **total** levy is how many they can theoretically raise, when their garrison and levy is full. The **current** is the number of troops they can currently raise (maybe they've just been at war, or some territories are recently conquered).

The **relative strength** I don't know. I thought it had to do with how many of those troops are currently unraised, however in this example the good King actually has a standing army getting their knickers handed to them by some helpful rebels.

Am I far off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumptions on total and current are correct.

As for relative strength, it is the size of the levy (total or current) as a percentage of the top liege. So it's always 100% for the top guy. It's usually not the case for his vassals. And if it is...he's in for some trouble =D

[image: Relative Strength]

Comment: So what about "current" and "total"? Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Yep, they are correct.