# CK2 - Others' potential army size

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Is there an accurate way to gauge the size of a potential enemy's total manpower without actually going to war and seeing his megastack smash you into pieces?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of existing questions, but these two questions should cover it - [1](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107055/how-can-i-find-out-how-big-an-opponents-realm-is), [2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126398/whats-the-difference-between-total-current-and-relative-strength/126408#126408). Ledger view is current size, iirc.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per anschauung's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between total, current and relative strength?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126398/whats-the-difference-between-total-current-and-relative-strength/126408#126408), but since that's a slightly different question:

The 'Realm Tree' view on a character's page will give you a good summary of their total manpower, as well as the individual contributions of their vassals. It's the right-most icon in the top left of the character page, just to the left of their house crest.